# "Failed to inject axe-core into one of the iframes!" error in AXE Accessibility

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I am using [AXE Core](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core) for Accessibility testing with Protractor. Used below method on each test teardown to run Accessibility check.

```js
  AxeBuilder(browser.driver).options(context.config.axe)
    .analyze(function(results) {
      deferred.resolve(results);
    });
```

with below AxeCore version, I am getting accessibility violations as expected.

```
"axe-core": "^2.0.5",
"axe-webdriverjs": "^0.2.0",
```

I have upgraded Axe-core version to the latest one. On executing the test it throws this **"Failed to inject axe-core into one of the iframes!**" error

```
"axe-core": "^3.5.0",
"axe-webdriverjs": "^2.3.0",
```

How can I resolve this error with the latest Axe version?

**Sample Protractor Framework used:**

https://github.com/angular/protractor-accessibility-plugin

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure what is the problem without looking at the site in question.

However, axe-webdriverjs tries to inject the axe script into each of the iframes on the page so it can run axe in each one (thus returning all results from the page, even from inside iframes). When this fails to do so, you get that error. This could be because one of the iframes has the `sandbox` attribute on it which would prevent script injection into it. If it does, you'll need to pass the `noSandbox: true` option to axewebdriver.